# Why were the liquids floating in the first episode of The Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In this episode the liquids in Barry's lab begin to float before he is struck, but I thought this only happened when a speedster time travels or there are tachyons present.

Given the above why are the liquids floating? What is causing them to float?

Comment: nice try devoe, we wont share any barrys secrets with you!

Comment: The liquid floating effect is used when the speed force itself comes in to play (SPOILER: we see it in later seasons when barry travels into the speed force and when he is freed from the speed force prison). In addition, I believe there is dialogue in S2-3 about how at that moment the speed force _chose_ Barry directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see it.

The sequence of events is:

- The Particle Accelerator "accident" sends out a shock wave (which travels across the city and through Barry).
- Barry walks over to his chain to open/close the skylight.
- The chemicals begin to float and leave their beakers.
- The lightning strikes him, knocking him into the chemicals.

I see two possibilities.

1. The shock wave is what caused the liquids to float.
2. The Speed Force caused the liquids to float to ensure that when Barry was struck by the lightning, he would make contact with the chemicals, enabling him to become The Flash.

Comment: I suspect, given the storm etc, Barry is actually CLOSING the skylight rather than opening it?

Comment: @Dave except he barely pulls on it, and then the lightning hits it and glass explodes everywhere, which make it look closed to me (after like 1 half of a pull).